# How to use MoveIt and ros_control (from setup assistant) to control Gazebo robot?

Tags: ros

I've noticed that in the MoveIt setup assistant, there is a "ROS Control" that auto-generates 2 files:
- ros_controllers.yaml
- ros_controllers.launch

I wanted to ask if it was possible to use these files to control my Gazebo robot? How can I do this?

The robot arm I am working with is https://github.com/Interbotix/widowx_arm/blob/master/widowx_arm_description/urdf/widowx.urdf.xacro